# Frame.quit usage in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently using Python 3 and am writing my first GUI program. I don't want to import tkinter as: `from tkinter import *` but rather, I want to import it as `import Tkinter` because of my understanding of the way modules work.

In the following code my quit button doesn't work. Why not?

```
import tkinter


class Main_Frame:

    def __init__(self, welk_window):
        top_Frame = tkinter.Frame(welk_window, width = "1", height = "1") 
        top_Frame.pack()

        self.Button_start = tkinter.Button(top_Frame, text = "Start", fg ="green", command=self.startMessage)
        self.Button_start.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

        self.Button_quit = tkinter.Button(top_Frame, text = "Quit", fg ="red", command=Frame.quit)
        self.Button_quit.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

    def startMessage(self):
        print("Start")


root = tkinter.Tk()     
master_window = Main_Frame(root) 
root.mainloop()
```

What am I doing wrong? I know it has something to do with calling the attribute Frame.quit. I tried using `Tkinter.Frame.quit`, however that didn't work either. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You're right that you have to name the class `tkinter.Frame` instead of just `Frame`.

And you're also right that won't solve anything.

Because the root problem is that you need to call the method on a `Frame` *instance*, not on the `Frame` *class*.

Fortunately, you have a ready reference to the relevant `Frame` instance lying around, from this line:

```
    top_Frame = tkinter.Frame(welk_window, width = "1", height = "1")
```

So, you can just use it:

```
    self.Button_quit = tkinter.Button(top_Frame, text = "Quit", fg ="red", 
                                      command=top_Frame.quit)
```

---

However, it's worth thinking about a bit of a redesign.

Normally, when you're creating classes for tkinter, you want to make your objects either directly be a widget, or be a controller for a widget. Your `Main_Frame` object just creates a frame widget at initialization time, then forgets it, so it's really neither.

---

To make `Main_Frame` be a frame, just inherit from `Frame` and use `self` everywhere you would have used `top_Frame`:

```
class Main_Frame(tkinter.Frame):

    def __init__(self, welk_window):
        super().__init__(welk_window, width = "1", height = "1") 
        self.pack()

        self.Button_start = tkinter.Button(self, text = "Start", fg ="green", command=self.startMessage)
        self.Button_start.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

        self.Button_quit = tkinter.Button(self, text = "Quit", fg ="red", command=self.quit)
        self.Button_quit.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

    def startMessage(self):
        print("Start")
```

---

To make it be a frame controller, just store `top_Frame` as an attribute, the same way you do with `Button_start`:

```
class Main_Frame:

    def __init__(self, welk_window):
        self.top_Frame = tkinter.Frame(welk_window, width = "1", height = "1") 
        self.top_Frame.pack()

        self.Button_start = tkinter.Button(top_Frame, text = "Start", fg ="green", command=self.startMessage)
        self.Button_start.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

        self.Button_quit = tkinter.Button(top_Frame, text = "Quit", fg ="red", command=self.top_Frame.quit)
        self.Button_quit.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

    def startMessage(self):
        print("Start")
```